# How can I obtain a negative random integer in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

How can I obtain a negative random integer in common lisp?
Is there some function in standard lib?

---- updated on 2012/06/15 ----
Perhaps I did not descript my question correctly. What I actually want is to get random integer between n and -n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply negation directly.

```
(- (random x))
```

An Edit for the revised question. This is less of a common lisp thing and more of a general programming thing.

```
(defun random-n (n)
  (- (random (1+ (* 2 n))) n))
```

Read up on `random` in [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_random.htm).

Comment: Perhaps I did not descript my question correctly. What I actually want is to get random integer between n and -n. I wrote a little function to obtain one, like this. (defun random-new (n) (if (= (random 2) 0) (- (random n)) (random n))) But still thank you for your answer.

Comment: Added to my answer above. Save you a call to random.

Comment: This method is so simple, I like it. But I will improve it. When we call function 'random', we get a integer in range of [0, n). So when I define a new random function, I want to get a integer in range of (-n, n). Follow your way, I define a new random funcion like this. (defun random-new (n)
  (- (random (- (* 2 n) 1)) (- n 1)))

Answer (score 2):

if you want random number from `-n` to `n` :

#### Edited, should be `2n+1` because random is from 0 to n (exclude n)

```
(defun my-random (n)
    (- (random (1+ (* 2 n))) n))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you'd expect, `(- -1 (random n))`, will give you a random integer between -n and -1 with (approximately) uniform probability, where n is any integer.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  The question was for negative random numbers, and this does the job, doesn't it?  Zero is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's already a good answer in here, I'll just add one more [funny answer](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/287/427/608.jpg) (also, mind you, it might be even more efficient then the correct answer!)

```
(boole boole-c1 (random (1- n)) 0)
```

Will provide you with what you seek!